# The program isn't running as expected

Tags: javascript, function, loops

The idea of the code is simple: Check the arguments types, if it is a number, add all the numbers. If the type is a string that has a number, extract the number from the string and add it to the other numbers extracted. If there are no numbers at all and only strings, return the message in the console: `"All are strings"`.

```
let result = 0;
function specialMix(...data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (typeof data[i] === "number") {
            result += data[i];
        } else if (typeof data[i] === "string") {
            if (typeof parseInt(data[i]) === "number") {
                result += parseInt(data[i]);
            }  else if (typeof parseInt(data[i]) === "NaN") {
                continue;
            } else if (result === 0) {
                console.log("All are strings");
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(specialMix(10, 20, 30)); // 60
console.log(specialMix("10Test", "Testing", "20Cool")); // 30
console.log(specialMix("Testing", "10Testing", "40Cool")); // 50
console.log(specialMix("Test", "Cool", "Test")); // All are Strings
```

The first test (console.log) for the code worked and gave the required result , but the rest of the tests gave `NaN` , and I don't understand why that happened. I don't understand what's wrong in the logic of the code.

Comment: You have defined `let result` outside the function. So it will be shared between the calls and once it's `NaN` it won't ever reset.

Comment: Also, `typeof(NaN) === 'number'`. You want `Number.isNaN(x)` instead.

Comment: Actually , the variable is declared outside the function .

Comment: Typo, it's defined outside but needs to be inside

Comment: I tried to declare the variable inside the function , but I got the same results .

Comment: There are 2 more major issues: You already assign `NaN` to the number before your `NaN` check, so even if you fixed your `NaN` check your result is already corrupted. Rember `0 + NaN === NaN`

Comment: The other issue is that your last `if` statement needs to be outside the loop. Otherwise it might trigger early or not at all

Comment: Get in the habit of debugging your own code with `console.log`. Run `typeof parseInt("x")` in the chrome console, which will clearly show you your issue. You also are completely guessing with `typeof parseInt(data[i]) === "NaN"`, don't guess at what code does, test it and log it to verify. Your if statement check is wrong, you instead want to check if the string character is a 0-9 digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should put `let result = 0` in your function to reset its value whenever you call the function again.
Then if type of the `data[i]` was not number, in your `else if` you can change your condition to check if `parseInt()` of that value is true or not (if not that means that in NAN) so you won't need another condition to check if that's NAN.

```js
function specialMix(...data) {
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (typeof data[i] === "number") {
            result += data[i];
        } else if (typeof data[i] === "string") {
            if (parseInt(data[i])) {
                result += parseInt(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (result == 0) return 'All are strings'
    return result;
}

console.log(specialMix(10, 20, 30)); // 60
console.log(specialMix("10Test", "Testing", "20Cool")); // 30
console.log(specialMix("Testing", "10Testing", "40Cool")); // 50
console.log(specialMix("Test", "Cool", "Test")); // All are Strings
```

At the and you can check if `result` is still 0 if yes it will return the message, else it will return the value of `result` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . I have just one another inquirement about the code above . How ( if (parseInt(data[i])) ) evaluates to true when the value in the parentheses evaluates to a number ?

Comment: @Mohammed - that is standard C-style boolean evaluation - if a number is not 0, it is true. If you want to be more specific, a lot of JavaScript programmers use `!!` before a value to "check its truthiness", so - `!!parseInt(data)`

Comment: @Mohammed, Actually number is also true (except 0 that doesn't affect the result)  so if the result was any number, the condition is true, but since `NAN` stands for `Not A Number` and is always false, so the condition will be false.